# The first $4$ primes $p$ for which $15347$ has a square root mod $p$ are $2, 17, 23,$ and $29$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, quadratic-residues

I am reading about [Quadratic Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve#Data_collection) article in wiki and I don't understand the sieve part.

The article says:

> The first $4$ primes $p$ for which $15347$ has a square root mod $p$ are
>   $2, 17, 23,$ and $29$

How $2,17,23,$ and $29$ been calculated? If you can, please explain me the idea and the exact calculation.

Comment: Use [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).

Comment: Note that $ 15347=103\cdot 149$ and use the above.

Comment: The real answer to your question is, I wrote a C program that looked for large numbers that could be factored with few primes over a small sieve, and picked one that looked the best.  Finding a 5 digit number that could be factored with 4 primes and a sieve of only 100 entries was the best I found.  Usually, it would take much larger sieves and many more primes (quadratic residues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use quadratic reciprocity, as suggested in the comments, but those primes are so small that a brute-force approach is also reasonable. To find out whether a large $n$ has a square root modulo a small prime $p$, first compute $x = n \bmod p$, and then check whether $y^2 \equiv x \bmod p$ for some $y \in \{0,1,\ldots,(p-1)/2\}$.

Comment: It worked for $y \in \{0,1,\ldots,p\}$ Tnx