# Solving the matrix in Quadratic sieve

Tags: calculus, number-theory

I am trying to implement the [quadratic sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) and I don't understand how to solve the matrix at the end. I will show you what I did and where I got stuck.

So I am trying to factor $149 * 103 = 15347$
I picked B smooth $11$, so my vector primes are $2,3,5,7,11$(I know that I was supposed to actually thieve and pick those $2,17,13,23$ values, but I don't understand this part so I asked a separate question about that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630277/the-first-4-primes-p-for-which-15347-has-a-square-root-mod-p-are-2-17), anyway it's irrelevant to what I am asking now).

Now I started to search for B smooth numbers that satisfy

$a^2 \equiv b^2$

I started from $a = \left\lfloor\sqrt{1534}\right\rfloor = 40$ and the first values I found are

- $a = 178^2$, $b = 990  = 2^1 3^2 5^1 7^0 11^1$
- $a = 182^2$, $b = 2430 = 2^1 3^5 5^1 7^0 11^0$
- $a = 219^2$, $b = 1920 = 2^7 3^1 5^1 7^0 11^0$
- $a = 221^2$, $b = 2800 = 2^4 3^0 5^2 7^1 11^0$

First I converted it to vectors and I only care about odd or even powers, so I made it binary.

$\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0& 1& 0& 1\\
1& 1& 1& 0& 0\\
1& 1& 1& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1& 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Since I want to know what subset equals to {0,0,0,0} I rotate it.

$\begin{bmatrix}
1& 1& 1& 0\\
0& 1& 1& 0\\
1& 1& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1\\
1& 0& 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Next I calculate the Echelon form.

$\begin{bmatrix}
1& 1& 1& 0\\    
0& 1& 1& 0\\      
0& 0& 0& 1\\    
0& 0& 0& 0\\  
0& 0& 0& 0  
\end{bmatrix}$

And now I am stuck, how can I understand from my last result if there is such subset and if there is how do I know what it is? If you can please give me a general explanation and also show me how it works with my example.